# What is the new "Management service" in the System settings?

Tags: 12.04, settings, landscape

In the Ubuntu 12.04 version, there is an item in the System settings under `System` category with name "Management Service". When I Clicked on it a new windows appears and asks for Installing `Landscape Client`.

**What is this "Management Service"?. Do I need this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I click onto it a message appears:

**Landscape client**

Landscape is an easy-to-use commercial systems management and monitoring service offered by Canonical that helps administrators manage multiple machines efficiently.

[Find out more...](https://landscape.canonical.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit of UI goodness to make registering to the Landscape web service easier for existing installs (as opposed to deploy time).

If you are not familiar with Landscape, it is Canonical's systems management tooling for enterprise users - see http://ubuntu.com/landscape to learn more.

Because this name was a little bit vague we've since changed it, in 12.10 you'll see it's now called "Landscape Service".